# How to setup URLs dynamically when using WAC and not loosing the tracking service system

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, web-analytics-connector

I am building URLs dynamically using AMPScript and values stored in a data extension. We are using Web Analytics Connector WAC, so the AMPScript vars are not interpreted properly by the WAC when sending the Email. To face this issue I have build all my dynamic urls as explained here (https://gist.github.com/MyCueCards/e72bfbacdc4e6d8405cf9b137a701ecf).

The urls are been built properly and working as expected. My issue now is that using this approach, we are passing over the WAC and the tracking service system is not generating the click.info.xxx/q=token associated url for tracking the clicks.

Is there any way of building the URLs dynamically using AMPSCript vars and having the system genrating the click.info.xxx/token associated url ?

I have been using RedirectTo() in conjunction with treatascontent() functions in any kind of combination but still is not working.

Comment: Do you have sample code?

Comment: Hi Macca, please have a look into the link attached. This is my code. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the code you provide, I would recommend doing changes along with what I have done below:

```
<!-- AMPscript Block -->
%%[
var @UTMstring1
set @UTMstring1 = "?utm_source=SFMC&utm_medium=email&utm_campaign="
var @UTMstring2
set @UTMstring2 = "&utm_content="
var @UTMstring3
set @UTMstring3 = "&utm_subscriber="

var @url1
set @url1 = "https://www.salesforce.com/eu/"

var @link1
set @link1 = Concat(@url1,@UTMstring1,emailname_,@UTMstring2,'Hello',@UTMstring3,subscriberid)
set @link1 = URLEncode(@link1)
]%%


<!-- snippets within HTML -->

This is the URL: <a href="%%=RedirectTo(@link1)=%%" target="_blank">https://www.salesforce.com/</a>
```

To summarize:
I have removed the `href=""` from your Concat function, and placed it into the HTML, wrapping `RedirectTo()` - which is required for the URL click tracking to work on SFMC, when storing URLs in AmpScript variables.

Additionally, I have tested this with WAC appending `cm_ven=ExactTarget&cm_cat=%%jobid%%` on top of the utm parameters added to the URL in Ampscript.

This results in following URL: https://www.salesforce.com/eu/?utm_source=SFMC&utm_medium=email&utm_campaign=Testers&utm_content=Hello&utm_subscriber=18657090&cm_ven=ExactTarget&cm_cat=20656

And, once sent out, the URL is wrapped in tracking, e.g.:https://cl.s50.exct.net/?qs=0a1b2c3d4e5f6g, and counted. Please observe the tracking URL will not be shown if you just preview the email in "Preview and Test" tab.

Comment: Hi Lucas, thanks for responding. I have already tried this option you mentioned, but the issue I am having is with the WAC because is not parsing and interpreting the redirectTo() function becuase is detecting the link. So doing something similar to your proposal the links are broken becuase of the WAC interception. This is one example of link result:  https://www.yyy.es/es-es/sale/c/as80000000/?utm_campaign=c1&utm_source=sfmc&utm_medium=email&utm_content=54843_%%%3dRedirectTo(Concat(%40linkURL%2c%))%3d%%

Comment: @EnriqueDiaz - please check my updated answer. It does also work with WAC.

Comment: Ok Lukas, let me try then. I will let you know !

Comment: Hi Lukas, I have already tested. Initially the URL is being build properly, I can see in the Sent Email the click.info.xxx/q=token being built properly, but when clicking into the link, the URL redirection is giving me an error becuase is broken. I copied and paste here the last part of the URL. You can see here: .......&utm_source=sfmc&utm_medium=email&utm_content=20200124_956837_Hero1-ES-ES%22&utm_campaign=AS_Promo_2019-sales2ndwave&utm_source=sfmc&utm_medium=email&utm_content=20200124_956837_%%%3dRedirectTo(%40link1)%3d%%

Comment: @EnriqueDiaz I suspect your WAC acting up. What do you have in there?

Comment: Hi Lukas, sure, WAC is acting up here. The email_XtraLinkParameters brand tag we setup in WAC is: 

utm_campaign=%%emailname_%%&utm_source=sfmc&utm_medium=email&utm_content=%%=format(xtshortdate ,"yyyyMMdd")=%%_%%jobid%%_%%linkname%% . What do you mean then ? With this code we should avoid WAC being intercepting the link definition ? I am aware that the way to avoid WAC acting up is building thhe URLS using concat() function. Perhaps the concat() function has to be included in the HREF definition ? Let me try and let you know. Best

Comment: It’a because %%linkname%% populates with the value of href if no link alias is specified. Use an iif() statement and indexof() in WAC to check for presence of % in value in %%linkname%% and default to something else if no alias is specified.

Comment: Hi Lukas, thanks a lot for your recomendations. I am now basically very closed to fix the issue. The only pending thing now is how to write the right syntax becuase all is working fine but the alias value is empty in the redirection. This is what I am including in the WAC Brand Tag: ...%%=IIF(IndexOf(AttributeValue('linkname'),'%')>0,v(@alias),AttributeValue('linkname'))=%%

Comment: Hi Lukas and Community, I would like to share with the solution. Finally it is properly working ! After 3 calls with Support we saw that the issue was with the way of referencing  %%linkname%% that was a bit tricky and differnent as usual because we had to include double quotes in the reference. So the extension to the Brand Tag was: %%=IIF(IndexOf("%%linkname%%","%")>0,@alias,"%%linkname%%")=%%